# Toggling between two classes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi :) I can't understand why my arrows aren't able to animate down the same way as they are animated up when user is clicking on it and when the downside panel is open. I've created two css classes: `open` and `closed` and I've used the `toggleClass` method but it seems to skip the fact that `closed` exists. Why ?

CSS:

```css
nav.open #headerp i{
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transition-duration:0.5s;           
}

nav.closed i{
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transition-duration:2s;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav li a i:first').on('click', function() {
        $('.forperson1').slideToggle();
        $('nav').toggleClass('open closed');
    });
});
```

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/ZJezYz)

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Your `transform` value is exactly the same for both "open" and "closed" states, so there's nothing to animate. The value you pass to `.rotate()` is not an *incremental* value, it's the *absolute* amount of rotation.

Comment: @freginold The arrows should rotate down by analogy to it's moving up. At this moment the arrows are animated up but when you click on it again (here class "closed"  should been toggled) they don't rotate slowly to it's initial state but just "switch" to it's initial state. It should be as in the original: paypal.com

Comment: You haven't specified _which property_ you want to transition. Instead of `transition-duration:0.5s;`, use `transition: transform .5s;`

Comment: @Pointy when I changed rotate() value to 90deg arrow started to behave as she doesn't see the "open" css class. It works as only one of the classes been accepted ...

Comment: How about changing it to `0deg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not having a “closed” class on your navbar, you are [toggling](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) the classes “open closed” together; they will be added (and removed) at the same time 'cause toggleClass will not find an existing class to toggle, adding\removing them both.

To have the effect you want, you can remove the closed class completely, give a starting transform to the `<i>` (which will be 0deg) and only toggle the open class.

**JS**

```
$('nav').toggleClass('open');
```

**CSS**

```
nav #headerp i {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition-duration:0.5s;
}
nav.open #headerp i{
  transform:rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Or, if you want to mantain your closed class, you need to give it a 0deg starting point (because, as it stands, it's rotating from -180deg to -180deg) and include it your navbar.

**CSS**

```
nav.closed #headerp i{
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition-duration:2s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar closed">
```

Otherwise, as I said above, the toggleClass will add\remove the “open closed” classes together.

Answer (score 0):

You should use check and change:

```
$("nav li a i:first").on("click", function() {
    if ($("nav").hasClass("open")) {
        $("nav").toggleClass("close");
    } else {
        $("nav").toggleClass("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will make it so the element has both an open and closed state at the same time. Probably not what the author intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your element is not a block element, which is required to to a rotation. See example below.

Also you are in the closed and open state have a rotation of -180 degrees... so it will always be -180 so long as as either class is applied to the element. I have set the closed to have 0 rotation in my example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        $('a').toggleClass('open closed');
    });
});
```

```css
.open span{
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(-180deg);
  transition-duration:0.5s;           
}

.closed span{
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition-duration:2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="open"><span>link</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I'm struggling with the second phase of the behaviour - I want that my "link caption" or "arrow" or sth else smoothly rotate back to it's previous position but it do it fast,automatically (also on Your's example) and I don't want that. Every onclick should generate toggle class - in consequence - smooth rotation up or down regards to class it current has.